# Get search results without refreshing the page

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have search button where user inputs data (year,week,page) and gets data in grid format. When user wants to search for another data,i have to refresh the page to get correct data.

I want to get a correct data without refreshing the page manually. I think this has something to do with ngOnDestroy but I am not understanding how to impliment this.

I have gone through many questions and post but did not understand it properly.

Below is my code.

**FlyerSearchComponent.ts**

```
export class FlyerSearchComponent {

  errorMessage: string;
  public flyers: Flyer[];
  public x: string;
  artnr: string;
  produkt: Produkt;
  imageUrl: string;

  private produktUrl = environment.apiUrl + 'static';

  constructor(private flyerhammService: FlyerHammService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location,
    private produktService: ProduktService) { };

  flyersearch(event, week: any, seite: any): Observable<Flyer[]> {
    let temp = week.split('-W');
    let jahr = temp[0];
    let woche = temp[1];
    let flyerBild: string;
    this.flyerhammService.getFlyer(jahr, woche, seite)
      .subscribe(
        flyers => {
          this.flyers = flyers;
          this.x = this.flyers[0].ArtNr;
        }
      )
      ).catch(
        error => console.log(error)
      );
  }
```

**FlyerSearchComponent.html**

```
<md-card class="default-card">
  <h1>{{ 'Suche Flyer' }}</h1>
</md-card>
<md-card class="default-card">
  <form id="flyer-search">
    <table class="calender" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput placeholder="{{ 'Weak and Year' }}" type="week" #week name="week" value="2017-W17">
          </md-input-container>
        </td>
        <td>
          <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput placeholder="{{ 'Seite' }}" type="number" #seite name="seite" value="01" min="01">
          </md-input-container>
        </td>
        <td>
          <md-card-actions align="end">
            <button md-raised-button color="primary" (click)="flyersearch($event,week.value, seite.value)">
              {{ 'Search' }}
              <md-icon>search</md-icon>
            </button>
          </md-card-actions>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</md-card>
<app-raster *ngIf="flyers!= null" [flyers]="flyers"></app-raster>
```

From FlyerSearchComponent, i am passing my data to RasterComponent.

Can anyone tell me how to get the correct data without refreshing the page?

Comment: If `getFlyer()` is changed to return an Observable instead of a Promise, you'll be able to use the `async` pipe in your templates, likely fixing your issue.

Comment: [Here's a StackBlitz showing a common pattern for service data retrieval with Observables and the async pipe.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a5zmej?file=src/app/app.component.ts) Without seeing your underlying data models and service, it's hard to help you further.

Comment: Okay...i will post my code again in question..

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of `flyers`:

```
public flyers: Observable<Flyer[]>;
```

Instead of calling `.subscribe()` on your `getFlyer()` observable, do something like this:

```
flyersearch(event, week: any, seite: any): Observable<Flyer[]> {
    let temp = week.split('-W');
    let jahr = temp[0];
    let woche = temp[1];
    this.flyers = this.flyerhammService.getFlyer(jahr, woche, seite);
}
```

I don't see where you're using `this.x`, but to get that set, you could use rxjs's `tap` operator (although there is probably a better way of doing this):

```
flyersearch(event, week: any, seite: any): Observable<Flyer[]> {
    let temp = week.split('-W');
    let jahr = temp[0];
    let woche = temp[1];
    this.flyers = this.flyerhammService.getFlyer(jahr, woche, seite)
        .pipe(
             tap(flyers => this.x = flyers[0].ArtNr)
         )
}
```

Then in your template, do:

```
<app-raster [flyers]="flyers | async"></app-raster>
```